# html type date upon click of date picker calendar opens up left bottom

Tags: html, sass, angular13

How to open calendar on right side or how to change calendar pop up position from left to right above the icon . I tried with styling css and using after and before

Comment: It’s impossible to say why something is happening without any code or details showing what you’re doing.